# How to GROUP BY a computed boolean expression in SQLite?

Tags: python, sql, sqlite, join, group-by

I have an SQLite DB of data from a month-long festival that looks in part like this:

```sqlite
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS performance_status (
    id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
    name TEXT UNIQUE       -- available, soldout, past, etc
)
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS performances (
    id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
    date INTEGER,           -- The date of the show
    sold_out_date INTEGER,  -- The date on which the showing sold out

    show_id INTEGER,
    status_id INTEGER,
    FOREIGN KEY(show_id) REFERENCES shows(id),
    FOREIGN KEY(status_id) REFERENCES performance_status(id),
    UNIQUE(date, show_id)
)
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS shows (
    id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
    name TEXT
)
```

I have a list of shows that have sold out ANY performance dates, sorted by the number of performances (days) that have sold out. Here is my query:

```sql
SELECT s.id, s.name, count(p.id) AS sellout_count
FROM shows AS s
    LEFT JOIN performances AS p ON s.id = p.show_id
    LEFT JOIN performance_status AS ps ON p.status_id = ps.id
WHERE ps.name = "soldout"
GROUP BY s.id
HAVING sellout_count > 0
ORDER BY sellout_count DESC
LIMIT 3
```

This works, and returns an array like this:

```
[(2100, 'Show 1', 25), (1286, 'Show 2', 25), (2936, 'Show 3', 24)]
```

So far so good. But I also need to know how many performance days a given show has, regardless of the sellout status. But the `WHERE` clause is limiting the selected rows to only those that are sold out.

If I `GROUP BY s.id, ps.name`, that will partition things beyond what I need, and return as many as 8 groups per show. I just want to group by the boolean "soldout or NOT soldout".

How can I do this in SQLite?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the `WHERE` clause, which not only filters out any statuses other than `'soldout'` but it also changes your `LEFT` joins to `INNER` joins because it also filters out any non-matching rows.

You should use conditional aggregation with the aggregate function `SUM()` (or `TOTAL()` if you use the query without the `HAVING` clause) to get the column `sellout_count` and `COUNT()` to get the number of performance days:

```
SELECT s.id, 
       s.name, 
       SUM(ps.name = 'soldout') AS sellout_count,
       COUNT(p.id) performance_days -- or COUNT(DISTINCT p.id)
FROM shows AS s
LEFT JOIN performances AS p ON s.id = p.show_id
LEFT JOIN performance_status AS ps ON p.status_id = ps.id
GROUP BY s.id
HAVING sellout_count > 0
```

Comment: Conditional aggregation is the feature I was missing. This is an even better solution than I was hoping for. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following subquery:

```sql
SELECT s.id,
       s.name,
       COUNT(p.id) AS sellout_count,
       (SELECT COUNT(p1.id)
        FROM performances AS p1
        WHERE p.show_id = p1.show_id
       ) AS performance_days
       ...
```